# Can't move li elements from one unorderted list to another

Tags: jquery

I have two un-ordered list

```
<ul id="#list1">
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
</ul>

<ul id="#list2"></ul>
```

and two buttons

```
<input id="add" name="yt1" type="button" value="<<" /><br />
<input id="remove" name="yt2" type="button" value=">>" />
```

If the button with the id add is pressed all elements from #list1 should be move to #list2. How do I move elements from one list to another using JQuery

I though of something like the below, but not sure how to do the actual moving

```
$("#add").click(function(){
$("#list1 li").each(function(){
//Do not know what to put in here
}
})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    $("#list1 li").appendTo('#list2');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/CqR5N/)

Also change your IDs from `<ul id="#list1">` to `<ul id="list1">`.

Comment: +1 - I somehow had it in my head that `.appendTo` didn't remove the matching elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
  //this will move selected items from yt1-list to yt2-list     
  $("#yt1 option:selected").appendTo("#yt2");

  //this will move all selected items from yt1-list to yt2-list
  $("#yt1 option").appendTo("#yt2");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      $('#list2').html( $('#list1').html() );
```

Comment: Any event handlers bound to the list elements will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Didn't test it, but it should work (logically).

```
$("#add").click(function(){
$("#list1 li").each(function(){
var holder;
$(this) = holder;
$(this).remove();
$('#list2').append();
}
});
```